# Can I disable SecureBoot, even though my motherboard doesn't give me the option to do that?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

It does not give me the option to run alongside windows during installation, tried to make Grub2 pop up manually, but it kept giving me an error. I run UEFI btw.

Comment: If you can boot the Ubuntu installer, Secure Boot is most likely not the problem here.

Comment: Please specify the question in detail.
I assume that you just installed ubuntu in your system. 
If so can you log into Ubuntu now?
How did you try to make Grub2 pop up manually?

Comment: Microsoft requires vendors to allow users to turn off Secure boot(at least for now). So there is a way. Some UEFI call it Windows or "other". Some require UEFI password (never lose that or may may have a brick). Otherwise check your motherboard/vendor's manual.

Comment: @JithinPavithran I tried to use boot-repair to restore Grub2, I also uninstalled Ubuntu and the partition for now, I will try again later, I'm just gathering answers on what the problem could be.

Comment: Oldfred, that's true for Windows 8/8.1 on x86 and x86-64 platforms. For ARM64 platforms (rare on anything but phones and tablets), Microsoft requires that Secure Boot can *not* be enabled. For Windows 10 on x86 and x86-64, the ability to disable Secure Boot is considered *optional* by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit of a non-sequitur. You've reported at least two unrelated issues, with an implied connection that does not exist in the real world. Specifically, from the title of your question....

> Can I disable SecureBoot, even though my motherboard doesn't give me the option to do that?

Chances are the option does exist, although you may not have identified it because it's sometimes hidden until you select some other option, or it may be named something non-obvious (such as under a "Windows mode" menu or something along those lines). See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) for examples of how to disable Secure Boot on six computers.

As noted in my comment to your question, Microsoft requires that Secure Boot be disable-able on computers that ship with Windows 8 or 8.1 for x86 or x86-64. With Windows 10, Microsoft has relaxed this requirement to an option, but as a practical matter, most vendors seem to be keeping the option.

Even if you can't disable Secure Boot, though, Ubuntu *should* work with it enabled. This brings me to the text of your question, which has nothing to do with the title....

> It does not give me the option to run alongside windows during installation

The closest thing to "run alongside [W]indows" in the Ubuntu installation process is an option to "install alongside" another OS. This option appears well after the Ubuntu installer has booted, so if this is the option to which you're referring, Secure Boot is ***NOT*** the problem. A Secure Boot problem will almost certainly manifest as an inability to boot Ubuntu -- including the Ubuntu installation medium. If Secure Boot doesn't like the Ubuntu installer, you won't get as far as a GRUB boot options menu, much less any Ubuntu installation messages. (By "GRUB boot options menu," I mean a menu showing options for how to boot, not a menu with options for how to install GRUB.)

A failure to see the "install alongside" option is common on EFI-based computers. Disabling Fast Startup (a *Windows* feature, not a firmware option with a similar name), as described [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) for Windows 8 or [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) for Windows 10, may work around this issue. If that fails, you'll need to install using the "something else" option, as described [here,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) among many other places.

> tried to make Grub2 pop up manually, but it kept giving me an error.

I don't know what you mean by this. If you mean that you couldn't boot the installer, then I don't understand your previous comment about not seeing an option to "run alongside." If you're saying that the installer failed to install GRUB, then you must be more precise. Please don't report that a command produced "an error"; to understand the problem, we must know the *exact* error message. If it's in a text-mode program, cut-and-paste the error message. If it's a GUI tool or a text-mode display that doesn't support cutting-and-pasting, take a screen shot, either with software or with a digital camera, and post it with adequate resolution to retain legibility.